# Best way to manage multilingual website SEO friendly

Tags: php, seo, multilingual

I have a question regarding the creation of a multilingual website. In short I would like to send online a website and present it translated in 4 languages.

The most important thing is that the website is SEO friendly.
I have read several articles about this topic and some of them were published here.
In the end I decided to create sub-folders like this:

- `www.example.com/es` for Spanish
- `www.example.com/de` for German
- and so on …

The main language will be English `www.example.com`.

Because it is the very first time I am dealing with this issue and I'd like to ask how to proceed.

At first sight, a similar approach makes me realize that each sub-folder `www.example.com/es` etc. will contain all the codes of the main site. This means that every time when I change something I have to copy/paste the change in each and every folder? Is there a more effective and dynamic way how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Rewrite URLs
   E.g: mysite.com/en FOR mysite.com?lang=en
   E.g 2: mysite.com/fr FOR mysite.com?lang=fr
2. Create a language array with combinaison of key => value in an inclusion file (e.g: inc.lang.php) such as
   'en_apple' => Apple
   'fr_apple' => Pomme
3. Replace terms to translate by your included array.

That's my way, it works for SEO (tested with Google tools) and it's light, because you have one directory to maintain for all your languages and it's invisible for users.

This is dynamic has you want, and you don't have to maintain 3 or 4 different folders each time you work on your website.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Moerg, thanks a lot for your answer. I have already created a similar tool which shows the languages with dynamic URL. I read an article about this topic and google advises against such approaches because of it's not friendly SEO implementation. Lot of SEO experts reccomend to use subdomain or subfolder and create different xml sitemaps...

Comment: I understand what you mean. That's what I do with rewriting, it looks like a subfolder, but it's not. rewriting will help you a lot with SEO, according to Google, because GoogleBot'll see /en like a real subfolder, your score will go up. I suggest to give a try with Google's Tools, you'll get a good result.

Comment: Hi Moerg, in this case I have to create only one sitemap with the related translation: 
  <url>
       <loc>http://example.com/interview-with-john-lennon.html
       <lastmod>2014-11-08T15:01:52+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>
  <url>
       <loc>http://example.com/intervista-con-john-lennon.html
       <lastmod>2014-11-08T15:01:52+00:00</lastmod>
       <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
       <priority>0.8000</priority>
  </url>

Comment: How do you value this tool? http://factorysoftdemos.com/mlsite/ It can be useful for my project?

Comment: That's a good practice for your sitemap. I suggest you to create a Google webmaster account and use Google's tools, it'll help ypu a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> At first sight, a similar approach makes me realize that each
>   sub-folder www.example.com/es etc. will contain all the codes of the
>   main site. This means that every time when I change something I have
>   to copy/paste the change in each and every folder? Is there a more
>   effective and dynamic way how to do that?

No, you don't need to copy all the code of the main site. You only need to create the HTML content for each language and store it correspondingly in each directory. Then you need to learn about [hreflang](https://ligatures.net/content/expertise/internationalization-multi-language-seo-checklist.html). It is not very hard, it is only about adding a couple of links in your header.